# How do I make a method to print a check in JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe

Following youtube tutorials I have created a `mypanel` class. I overrode the `paint` method in the class and called `drawRect()` and other functions in `paint()`.

What I want to do is to make a method which takes number of boxes as parameter and creates a check. Currently, I am able to make a check but since the paint is overridden I am unable to pass the number of boxes.

Following is the implementation of `mypanel` class:

```
package com.example;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public mypanel extends JPanel {
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        int noofchecks = 10;
        for (int j = 0; j < noofchecks; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < noofchecks; i++) {
                if (j % 2 == 0) {
                    if (i % 2 == 0) {
                        g.setColor(Color.white);
                    } else {
                        g.setColor(Color.black);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (i % 2 == 0) {
                        g.setColor(Color.black);
                    } else {
                        g.setColor(Color.white);
                    }
                }
                g.fillRect(5 + (i * 20), 5 + (j * 20), 20, 20);
            }
        }
    }

    public void makerect(Graphics g) {
    }
}
```

This is `example` class calling `mypanel` class:

```
package com.example;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class example extends JFrame {

   example() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        example ex = new example();
        ex.setVisible(true);
        ex.load(10);
    }

    public void load(int noofchecks) {
        int x = (noofchecks * 20) + 30;
        int y = x + 30;
        setSize(x, y);
        mypanel panel = new mypanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.white);
        add(panel);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) class names should start with an upper case character. 2) custom painting should be done by overriding paintComponent(...). 3) the painting method should only paint the current state of the component. So you need to keep a model of the current state. Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/). It demonstrates one way to do all of the above. So maybe you need an ArrayList of "checks" to paint?

Comment: What do you mean by 'check'? DYM a checkmark like ✔ this? Is this GUI for a board game? If so, what game?